# Geo distance sort in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, search

Referring to the [ES documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/search-request-sort.html), we can sort on the base of geolocation if lat and lon are both in the same geotype field.

```
{
    "sort" : [
        {
            "_geo_distance" : {
                "pin.location" : [-70, 40],
                "order" : "asc",
                "unit" : "km",
                "mode" : "min",
                "distance_type" : "arc",
                "ignore_unmapped": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

In my case, I have the location in separate float fields for both latitude and longitude. How can I sort on geo-distance if I can't change my schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a new index with a new mapping which will contain [geo point](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html) field instead of two fields (lat, long). Then, you need to index data into the newly created index. Have a look into [Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) - will help you with moving data into the new index.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to avoid that. But I guess that's the only workaround. Thanks.